# Refrigerator does not have a coil visible in back

Tags: refrigerator

Is it a defect if a refrigerator does not have a coil at back? If it has a coil, where is it located?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What kind of 'fridge are you talking about? Does it cool? What is your concern?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of modern home refrigerators do not have a coil on the back, maybe all of them. I think in most cases the coil is located underneath. The heat from the coil helps to evaporate the water from the defrost cycle which has drained into a pan also underneath.